# Variable size (run time) input Simulink Matlab

Tags: matlab, size, simulink

I'm having big problems with variable size signals in simulink.
I have a matlab function block with a function which should accept a variable size (run time) array and it need to evaluate the output. In particular the input array is a 1xn array with integers and every integer represent a section of a trajectory (for example a sequence of: straight line, straight line, circle, half circle, straight line could be represented by the array [1 1 2 3 1]).
This array, so the trajectory, could change in the simulation (path planning for robots) but i get tons of errors.
I have put variable size in the data/ports for the input (without size) and for the outputs (with size representing the upper bound). If I put an uppe bound in input, simulink expects exactly an input with that dimension even if I put variable size.

I think Simulink generates errors because not knowing the input size, it isn't able to allocate memory.
Some help?

Thank you

A little part of code...prim is the variable size input, while all the outputs are variable size.

```
function [x, y, vx, vy, ax, ay, tf] = trajectoryPlanUniform(prim, discr, xdiscr, 

ydiscr, xi, yi, vmax, amax)

len = size(prim, 2);

tf = zeros(1, len+1); tf(1, 1) = 0;
x = zeros(6, len); y = zeros(6, len); 
vx = zeros(6, len); vy = zeros(6, len); 
ax = zeros(6, len); ay = zeros(6, len);

xitemp = xdiscr; yitemp = ydiscr;
vxitemp = 0; vyitemp = 0; vftemp = vmax;
axitemp = 0; ayitemp = 0; aftemp = amax;

xytot = zeros(2,len+1);
xytot(1,1) = xi; xytot(2,1) = yi;

for i = 1:len
    [x(:,i), y(:,i), vx(:,i), vy(:,i), ax(:,i), ay(:,i), tf(i+1)] = trajectoryCallUniform(prim(i), discr, xitemp, yitemp, vxitemp, vyitemp, vftemp, axitemp, ayitemp, aftemp, tf(i), vmax, amax);

    [xitemp, yitemp, vxitemp, vyitemp, axitemp, ayitemp] = calculateTrajectoryUniform(prim(i), x(:,i), y(:,i), vx(:,i), vy(:,i), ax(:,i), ay(:,i), tf(i+1));

    xytot(1,i+1) = xitemp;
    xytot(2,i+1) = yitemp;

    if i == (len - 1)
        vftemp = 0;
        aftemp = 0;
    end
end

end
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Can you share your code?

Comment: `tf` is a function in the `Control System Toolbox`. You should rename your `tf` variable to something else.

Comment: Showing the code is unlikely to enable us to help you.  What are some of the error messages?

Comment: MATLAB Function Interface Error: The signal at input port 1 (prim) of 'modelTrajectory/Subsystem1/MATLAB Function/ SFunction ' is a variable-size signal with a nondiscrete sample time. The sample time for any variable-size signal must be discrete.

Simulation is running with fixed step time or I tried a zero-order hold or memory or delay and it didn't work. BTW I had others errors before and with another simulation. I need to know how to use variable-size inputs in embedded functions...

Comment: When you used a zoh or delay block and "it didn't work", did you get the same, or a different error message?  If different, what was it?

Comment: The following works: Your code with the function calls replaced with random data; input 1 defined as var-size inherited (-1); the outputs defined as var-size [6 10] (just using 10 as an upper bound); scalar constants into ports 2 and 3; input 1 generated in a similar way to the *Creating a Variable-Size Signal from Fixed-Size Signals* section of [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/simulink-models-using-variable-size-signals-demos-modeling-features-variable-size-signals-or-type-varsizedemos-.html).  Does that work for you, and can you modify it to suit the rest of your model?

Comment: What is the sample time of your input signal (prim) when you display the sample times in the model (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-view-sample-time-information.html)? The error message seems to indicate it isn't discrete, which it needs to be.

Comment: New error, putting unit delay in another position: MATLAB Function Interface Error: Block 'Unit Delay' contains states that require resetting whenever the input signal sizes vary. The output signal sizes of block 'modelTrajectory/Subsystem1/' depend on its input signal values. Consider placing 'Unit Delay' in an Enabled/Function-Call/Action Subsystem and setting the parameter 'Propagate sizes of variable-size signals' on the corresponding control port block to: 'Only when enabling' for an Enabled or a Function-Call Subsystem; or 'Only when execution is resumed' for an Action Subsystem.